# jQuery: Sorting Divs Based on their ID, Based to ID List

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting

If have an array of Javascript IDs

```
var myArray = ['2', '1', '3'];
```

Now, I also have a group of DIVS with corresponding ID.

```
<div id='container'>
   <div id='item1'>1</div>
   <div id='item2'>2</div>
   <div id='item3'>3</div>
</div>
```

Is there an easy way to sort these divs based on the array order? I have bounced around the idea of just looping through the divs and using `insertBefore()` and `insertAfter()` to re-arrange the items, but I am wondering if there is a better way..

**This is what I've come up with so far ([JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/CQXmW/))**

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.jaySort= function(prefix, lst) {
        var prev=null;
        for (var x=0; x<lst.length; x++){
            if (!prev) prev = $('#placeHolder');
            $('#' + prefix + lst[x]).insertAfter(prev);
            prev = $('#' + prefix + lst[x]);
        }
    };
})( jQuery );  


///////////////////////////////////////////

var myArray = ['2', '1', '3'];
$('#container').jaySort('item', myArray);
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the accepted answer below, the code has been refined to:

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.jaySort= function(prefix, lst) {
        for (var x=0; x<lst.length; x++)
            $(this).append($('#' + prefix + lst[x]));
    };
})( jQuery );  
$('#container').jaySort('item', ['3', '2', '1']);
```

Comment: what's wrong with what you have ?

Comment: Pretty neat solution, you'll have to loop through all items anyway

Comment: I guess nothing is **wrong** with it.. was just wondering if there was a better way, perhaps without looping.

Comment: I was able to remove the following two lines and it still seemed to work: `<div id='placeHolder'></div>` and `if (!prev) prev = $('#placeHolder');`

Comment: Thanks Mully. Nice find.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This also works(and is shorter)

```
<div id='container'>
   <div id='item1'>1</div>
   <div id='item2'>2</div>
   <div id='item3'>3</div>
</div>

var myArray = ['2', '1', '3'];

$.each(myArray,function(index,value){
   $('#container').append($('#item'+value));
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9Wb5/6/)

Comment: I like the `append()` change. Updated to a mix of both of our code. http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/CQXmW/